# 12V to 3.3V using LM3489

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

I ran into an issue with the LM3489 not actually attempting to switch the transistor at all. I'm not sure why it won't start up. PGATE sits at 12V, VCC and when watching it seems to make no attempt to actually start up, meaning the transistor never actually turns on.

I've also tried adding a 0.1uF capacitor across the input, too. I've tried using a 10uH inductor and also tried a lower RSENSE value. I built two boards with the same result on both, double checked all the silkscreens and connections actually on the PCB and they look ok.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

EDIT - R3 is 24kOhm
Edit2 - So now it's intermittently working, if i unplug it for a while, half an hour, it takes around a minute to turn on. But then immediately turns on when i unplug it and plug it back in straight away. Seems like a capacitance issue but i'm not sure what its from

[image: Circuit Schematic]

Comment: what value is R3?

Comment: R3 is 24kohm the same ass in the datasheet

Comment: Do you have access to an oscilloscope? Could you probe pin 1,4,5, and 7 to maybe get a guess? Other than that, this really looks like the circuit from the datasheet to me, as well. If really *nothing* happens, … how sure are you the IC is OK?

Comment: I do, Pin 1 and pin 4 have a 50mV oscillating signal on them, looks like a super noisy sin wave. pin 5 is dc around 11V and pin 7 is at VCC, 12V. That's what is confusing me as well. I'm pretty sure its not a faulty IC, i've built two separate boards with it and swapped out the IC once on both as well.

Comment: I think that info might be very useful, even if I don't immediately see the solution from it. Maybe add it to your question! 50 mV is not very much, but it does mean something is happening! Bit confusing that Pgate is constantly at VCC, since that would be the only thing that should lead to achange of  the feedback value! You say "50mV oscillating signal": around which voltage does it oscillate (i.e., using DC coupling on your scope)?

Comment: Have you mentioned what the output voltage is?

Comment: What is your board layout looking like? Did you follow the recommended one? Also is it a legit or questionable source for the part?

Comment: It oscillates around 0V, yeah i would've thought that would trigger the feedback. I'm not using the recommended layout but i've followed most of the guides, the input cap is the only thing that's not that close to the rest of it, maybe 5cm away?, but that shouldn't be enough for it not to function should it?

Comment: EN (pin 3) should read about 8VDC just for verification. What timebase do you use at probing? Would you see very fast things in µs range?

Comment: hmmmm regarding your edit: triple-check your inductor, and your soldering, and the ground connection